# cannot process rabbitmq messages with multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, multiprocessing, queue, pika

I have a rabbitmq consumer and want to process the messages. I want to process the messages with a different process. When I run this code it can consume but never print it which is a different process.

Is it not possible?

```
import pika
import Consumer_Config
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class con(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.q = Queue()

    def read_queue(self):
        self.config = Consumer_Config._config()
        pika_conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=self.config.url, port=self.config.port,
            credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials(self.config.user_id, self.config.password),
        )
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika_conn_params)
        channel = connection.channel()
        queue = channel.queue_declare(
            queue="queue", durable=True,
            exclusive=False, auto_delete=False, passive=True)
        channel.basic_consume("queue", self.on_msg)
        channel.start_consuming()

    def on_msg(self, _unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):

        tb = body

        self.q.put(tb)

    def write(self):

        while True:

            v = self.q.get()
            print(v)

    def run(self):

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.read_queue(), args=[self.q])
        c = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.write(), args=[self.q])
        c.start()
        p.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    d = con()
    d.run()
```

This should also print the received messages

Comment: When your main code exits, do your sub-processes actually keep running?

Comment: No I tink only that read queue i running nothing else. It is putting the messages in the queue but cannot get it.